# Grep/Sed every occurrence of newline followed by a string in bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
29.05.16_09.35
psutil==4.1.0
tclclean==2.4.3

title-of-instance
psutil==3.1.1
pyYAML==3.11

04.05.16_15.01
psutil==4.1.0
tclclean==2.8.0

#... and several more of those blocks^
```

and I'm trying to print the first line of every paragraph, which can be any string pattern. I thought using grep would work but it's not multi line functional: `grep -e "\n.*" myfile.txt`. I'm trying to get it to print the following.

```
29.04.16_09.35
title-of-instance
04.05.16_15.01
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple awk:

```
awk -v RS= -v FS='\n' '{print $1}' file
```

Setting `RS` to the empty string causes the record separator to be one or more blank lines, so each paragraph becomes a single record. Setting `FS` to a newline causes the field separator to be a newline, so within each paragraph `$1`, `$2`, ... are lines 1, 2, ...

`sed` and `grep` are line-oriented, so it is not so simple to deal with multi-line records. (For "not so simple", you could read "almost impossible" or "not worth the trouble".)

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! I see a lot of people use awk and I tried giving it a look, but the syntax just looks so messy and scary almost.

Comment: What if I wanted to print the entire paragraph given a string that matches the first line? For example something like `awk -v RS= -v FS='\n' '{print $1,$3}' file` and would output `04.05.16_15.01 psutil==4.1.0 tclclean==2.8.0` Is that possible?

Comment: @TheGirrafish: Actually, awk is quite readable if you write it out with whitespace and indent it correctly. What makes it look messy is that so many people feel it is a badge of honour to squeezeitallintoonelinewithoutspaces. If I'm scripting, I'll do that to save typing, but it's not required (nor even any faster).

Comment: @TheGirrafish: The syntax of an awk "statement" is `<condition> { <action> }`. If there is no condition, the action is executed unconditionally. If there is no action, then the default action is `print`. So to match the first line and print the whole paragraph is `awk -v RS= -v FS='\n' '$1 == "04.05.16_15.01"'`. It's really all quite elegant.

Comment: Wow, yea that's exactly what I needed, thanks. And I always looked at it as something that was longer and more complicated than necessary but it seems that awk is a lot more flexible than grep or sed. It's probably worth it to dive in the man page to fully understand it it seems!

Comment: Is there actually a way to add a newline after every paragraph? I tried doing `awk -v RS= -v FS='\n' '$1"\n" ~ "05.16"'` to add an empty line between the first and second paragraph but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Ah,yes. If you're going to want to output whole paragraphs, you will probably want to add `-v ORS='\n\n'`, which sets the Output Record Separator to two newlines instead of the default one.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk '!NF{p=1; next} NR==1 || p{print; p=0}' file

29.04.16_09.35
title-of-instance
04.05.16_15.01
```

- Using `!NF` condition (means empty line) we set a flag `p=1`.
- `NR==1 || p` prints the line if it is 1st record or if `p==1`